# '1004': "The sort reference is not valid."

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a range within a separate sheet. 
However, I keep getting this message:

```
 '1004': "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.
```

I have checked the ranges and they all exist and are working.

The code is below:

```
Dim EmpBRange As String

EmpBRange = Sheets("EmployeeData").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("EmployeeData").Range("K3:K" & EmpBRange).Sort Key1:=Range("K3:K" & EmpBRange), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
       OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
       DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I suspect you need to fully qualify the `Key1` range, because you are calling the code from a different sheet:

```
Worksheets("EmployeeData").Range("K3:K" & EmpBRange).Sort Key1:=Worksheets("EmployeeData").Range("K3:K" & EmpBRange)
```

This is generally a good idea.

Comment: When typing this code manually, the VBA editor suggests `xlSortRows` or `xlSortColumns` for Orientation, and does not include `xlTopToBottom` in its suggestions.  `xlTopToBottom` = `xlSortColumns`, _not_ `xlSortRows`.  I was confused by this, which was causing the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use the `Sort` method but from Powershell. And I only got `The sort reference is not valid` part without the  `Make sure it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank` part. This is how I got here.

My issue was due to having disregarded an argument to the `Sort` call. If you look closer to the documentation you will see there is a `Type` parameter tucked away in the middle of the key and order params:

> expression .Sort(Key1, Order1, Key2, Type, Order2, Key3, Order3, Header, OrderCustom, MatchCase, Orientation, SortMethod, DataOption1, DataOption2, DataOption3)

I have passed `$null` for that one and my method call started working. The next strange thing was that for some reason `Key2 / Order2` was disregarded. I am using all 3 keys to sort my data. The fix to that was to swap `Key2 / Order2` with `Key3 / Order3` arguments within the method call. Strangely, it has worked.