# Access VBA Sort: Error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access

Note: the solution to this is the same as ['1004': "The sort reference is not valid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296400/1004-the-sort-reference-is-not-valid)
but should probably be kept because for whatever reason, I received a different error text, so I see other people having potentially the same error but not seeing that the above solution is the same.

I am trying to process 5 related .csv files, with 4 of them needing to be sorted to get the key relationships correct for processing. We're talking a separate set of files for each month, several years of data, so presorting them is not a preferred option. Anyway, I get the above error when I try to sort. My original code called "sortSheet" (commented out below, but included after the code), I thought moving it inline might solve the problem but it's not happening, can anyone give me any insight to what's causing this? Here's the current code snippet:

```
filename = Dir(fullFolder + "HapDiagnosis.csv")
Dim wbDiag As Excel.Workbook
Dim shDiag As Excel.Worksheet
Set wbDiag = xL.Workbooks.Open(fullFolder + filename)
xOpenDiag = True
Set shDiag = wbDiag.Sheets(1)
lastRow = shDiag.Cells(shDiag.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
'sortSheet shDiag, "C", lastRow
shDiag.Range("A1:C" + CStr(lastRow)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), _
        Key2:=Range("A1"), _
        Header:=xlYes, _
        MatchCase:=False
```

I've heard that using ".Select" is not a good idea, but I got the same error using this subroutine:

```
Private Sub sortSheet(ByRef sh As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rightCol As String, _
                ByVal lastRow As Long)
  With sh.Range("A1:" + rightCol + CStr(lastRow))
    .Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=Range("A1"), _
        Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify your key ranges, `Key1:=sh.Range("B1")`, etc.

Comment: BINGO! And I know I had that in there. I think I backed out some changes, I must've gone too far. Thanks! Wish I could give you credit for this as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['1004': "The sort reference is not valid."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296400/1004-the-sort-reference-is-not-valid)

Comment: Why do you need to sort in Excel? Access SQL can robustly sort and Access VBA can import csv files.

Comment: I understand that. Loading the files for one month exceeds 100 megabytes and it's not in a format for final use. Some of the data have problematic values that get lost when I import, yet don't trigger an error. Normalizing the data changes it from 5 files into 17 tables at less than half the size of importing just the main file. By processing as Excel I can fix data that needs fixing, purge the data that should be purged, I avoid having to manually handle import errors, I don't lose any values and I don't have to delete the imported data when finished.