# VBA Runtime 1004 "reference not valid" - pivot refresh macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this very simple code which I have embedded into a button to refresh pivots:

```
Sub Button5_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DD").PivotTables("test").PivotCache.REFRESH
End Sub
```

In the photo below you can see the worksheet I am working on, and the name of the pivot.

It looks like I have the code pointing at the right things so I can't understand why I get this error. I have also tried it without using ThisWorkbook.

Workbook photo

[image]

Comment: How many pivot tables are in the entire workbook?  Have you tested it with the generic PivotTables(1) to see if the name isn't being accepted?

Comment: Can you give also a screenshot of the error? Is it "Sort reference not valid?" If this is the case take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296400/1004-the-sort-reference-is-not-valid

Comment: The error is simply "Reference not valid".

Comment: Hi Cyril, yes I have tested with generic name and got the same error, thats why I named it just so I could be sure it was pointing to the correct table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the data in `PivotTables("test")` in "DD" worksheet, you need to first update the `PivotCache` with the updates in the Range the `PivotTable` retrieves it's data from. And afterwards to `Refresh` the table.

I've used the line below to define the `Range` for the `PivotCache` (just for this code to run):

```
Set PvtDataRng = Worksheets("PivotDataSheet").Range("A1:E100")
```

Modify the Sheet's name and needee range to fit your data.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button5_Click()

Dim PvtTbl                  As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                As PivotCache
Dim PvtDataRng              As Range

' Set/Update Pivot Data Range
Set PvtDataRng = Worksheets("PivotDataSheet").Range("A1:E100") ' <-- just an example

' Create/Update Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

' Set the Pivot Table (already created, otherwise need to create it)
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("DD").PivotTables("test")

' refresh the Pivot Table with the latest Pivot Cache
With PvtTbl
    .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    .RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: One follow up - How do I add a second pivot table to this code? I have two tables that I would like the button to refresh