# VBA sort not working properly when sorting on values that are produced by formula

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a sheet of values that I want to sort with VBA.  I want to sort them in descending (reverse alphabetical) order by a particular header.  My sheet looks like this:

```
   A            B            C
1  Date Opened  Date Closed  Status
2  07/12/17     07/15/17     closed
3  07/16/17                  open
```

The value of  column C is calculated, so that if there's nothing in the "Date Closed" column, the status is set to "open" automatically.

I want to use VBA to sort the table by Column C in reverse alphabetical order, so that open tickets appear before closed tickets.  This is the VBA I'm trying to use:

```
Sub Sort_Status()
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C3")
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

If I run this on my data table with the formula in it, I get the error: `1004: The sort reference is not valid.  Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.`

However, if I paste these values into a new sheet (e.g. so that column C has just the values "closed" or "open", but not the formula), the same code works without errors.

I can also manually perform a sort in Excel on the sheet with the formulas, and it works fine there.

Other troubleshooting steps I've tried:

- [Another issue had the same error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296400/1004-the-sort-reference-is-not-valid), and it was due to calling the subroutine from another sheet.  However, this subroutine is simply in Modules and isn't being called from another sheet.
- Checked through online tutorials like [this](https://analysistabs.com/vba/sort-data-descending-order-excel-example-macro-code/) and [this](https://trumpexcel.com/sort-data-vba/) and tried using their code to see if I had the same issue

Comment: yeah just tested it. hold a moment or so.

Comment: Step 1 would be, obviously, just record a macro of doing it manually, and modify the macro if needed :)

Comment: Yeah, that's actually where I started and I've been stripping down the code from there.  It works with a recorded version but something's going wrong somewhere.

Comment: You might want to do `.SortFields.Clear` first inside your `With` block. I'm not sure that will fix it, but it would get rid of any previously existing sort fields, which might've been specified incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to have done it.  What would cause that, though?  It's not a sorted table or anything so I don't see where other rules would come from and this was an entirely new document I created to isolate my problem.

Comment: Must've come from previous debugging attempts. The rules are added sequentially and the error won't raise until/unless you try to `.Apply` in which case a single bad rule will cause that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never liked working with the `ActiveSheet.Sort`, preferring the more explicit `Range.Sort`. This seems to work for me:

```
Range("A1:C3").Sort Range("C1"), xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Also: You might want to do `.SortFields.Clear` first inside your `With` block. I'm not sure that will fix it, but it would get rid of any previously existing sort fields, which might've been specified incorrectly.