# My sort procedure runs on the first sheet but not on the other

Tags: excel, vba

A sorting procedure must be applied to several worksheets with different contents. So I opted for the solution "for each sh in worksheets...". 
This sorting procedure runs perfectly for the first selected sheet.
On the second sheet, a message "Run time error 1004 The sort reference is not valid" is displayed on the Apply instruction despite the fact that the different variables display correct values.
Referring to "['1004': "The sort reference is not valid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296400/1004-the-sort-reference-is-not-valid)", I changed "With sh.Sort" to "With sh.Range(startcell, lastcell).Sort" which generates the error "Unable to get the sort property of the range class".
Could a member of the forum help me solve this problem?
In advance, thank you

This sort procedure runs on the first sheet but not on the others.

```
Sub sortData()
Dim startcell As Range, lastcell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim x_Birth As Long, lastcell_Birth As Long
For Each sh In Worksheets
With sh
        If Left(sh.Name, 2) = "B_" Then
            .Columns(5).Insert
            .Cells(1, 5) = "Y_Birth"
            lastcell_Birth = sh.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For x_Birth = 2 To lastcell_Birth
                .Cells(x_Birth, 5) = Right(.Cells(x_Birth, 4), 4)
            Next
            Set startcell = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))
            Set lastcell = Range(.Cells(lastcell_Birth, 7), .Cells(lastcell_Birth, 7))
            With sh.Sort
                 .SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("F1"), Order:=xlAscending
                 .SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("E1"), Order:=xlAscending
                 .SetRange Range(startcell, lastcell)
                 .Header = xlYes
                 .Apply
            End With
            sh.Columns("E:E").Select
            Selection.Columns.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the range you want to sort, based on which column are there headers in the rows?

Comment: Hello, the range changes with each sheet. It is determined by the variables "Startcell" = first cell of the sheet and "Lastcell" = last cell containing data.
All columns have headers but not rows. I would like to remind  that the procedure works on the first sheet but not on the others.  Gihem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sortData()

    Dim startcell As Range, lastcell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x_Birth As Long, lastcell_Birth As Long

    For Each sh In Worksheets

        With sh

            If Left(.Name, 2) = "B_" Then

                .Columns(5).Insert
                .Cells(1, 5) = "Y_Birth"

                lastcell_Birth = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    For x_Birth = 2 To lastcell_Birth
                        .Cells(x_Birth, 5).Value = Right(.Cells(x_Birth, 4).Value, 4)
                    Next

                Set startcell = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1))

                Set lastcell = .Range(.Cells(lastcell_Birth, 7), .Cells(lastcell_Birth, 7))

                .Sort.SortFields.Clear

                With .Sort
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("E1"), Order:=xlAscending
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=sh.Range("F1"), Order:=xlAscending
                    .SetRange sh.Range(startcell, lastcell)
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .Apply
                End With

                .Columns("E:E").Columns.EntireColumn.Delete

            End If

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Safer to use `.SetRange sh.Range(startcell, lastcell)` given that we don't know where the code is.

Comment: there were some lines that by mistake i forgot to add "." before range or cells. Now i think is ok.

Comment: Great. 
sortfields.clear solves the problem Many thanks

Comment: You need `sh.Range` since it's inside a `With` block that refers to the `Sort`, not the sheet.